# How do I properly combine UNION with LIMIT?

Tags: database

I'm trying to get content from database divided by category. I want strictly max 4 entries of type "people" and 4 other entries of type "organization".

I tried to do it like that:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('n', array('title','type'))
->fields('i', array('field_image_fid'))
->fields('f', array('uri'))
->condition('n.title', '%'. db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE')
->condition('type', array('people'))
->range(0,4);
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_image', 'i', 'i.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->leftJoin('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = i.field_image_fid');

$query2 = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('n', array('title','type'))
->fields('i', array('field_image_fid'))
->fields('f', array('uri'))
->condition('n.title', '%'. db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE')
->condition('type', array('organization'))
->range(0,4);
$query2->leftJoin('field_data_field_image', 'i', 'i.entity_id = n.nid');
$query2->leftJoin('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = i.field_image_fid');

$query->union($query2, 'UNION');
$result = $query
->execute();
```

The problem is that this query is returning only the first 4 occurrences of people or organization combined. So if there are 4 people returned by the query, I will not be able to see any organization.

I also tried something like this:

```
    $query = db_query('

        SELECT p.title,p.type 
            FROM node as p
            WHERE p.type = :type 
            LIMIT 4'
        , array(':type' => 'people',':type1' => 'organization'))->fetchAll();

$query2 = db_query('

        SELECT o.title,o.type 
            FROM node as o
            WHERE o.type = :type1 
            LIMIT 4'
        , array(':type' => 'people',':type1' => 'organization'))->fetchAll();


$query->union($query2, 'UNION');
```

or like this:

```
$result = db_query('

    SELECT title,type 
        FROM {node} 
        WHERE type = :type 
        LIMIT 4 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title,type 
        FROM {node} 
        WHERE type = :type1 
        LIMIT 4'
    , array(':type' => 'people',':type1' => 'organization'))->fetchAll();
```

But these two approaches are only returning the 4 people and no organizations, I mean never..

Thank you if you can help!

--------------------EDIT--------------------

Thank you for your comment Clive. I hadn't tried yet to do it directly in plain SQL.

The query is something like that

```
(SELECT title,type FROM node WHERE type = 'organization'  LIMIT 4) 
UNION
(SELECT  title,type FROM node WHERE type = 'people'  LIMIT 4)
```

I didn't know but the parentheses are necessary to act as I need. Like that I get 4 of each, then 8 maximum in total.

So the same in drupal using db_query is something like:

```
$result = db_query('

(SELECT title,type 
    FROM {node} 
    WHERE type = :type 
    LIMIT 4 )
UNION ALL
(SELECT title,type 
    FROM {node} 
    WHERE type = :type1 
    LIMIT 4)'
, array(':type' => 'people',':type1' => 'organization'))->fetchAll();
```

I don't know if it's possible to do the same with db_select

--------------EDIT2---------------------------

Regarding to Molot comments, I changed my query to:

```
    $subquery_1 = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('title','type'))
    ->fields('i', array('field_image_fid'))
    ->fields('f', array('uri'))
    ->condition('n.title', '%'. db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->condition('type', array('people'))
    ->range(0,3);
    $subquery_1->leftJoin('field_data_field_image', 'i', 'i.entity_id = n.nid');
    $subquery_1->leftJoin('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = i.field_image_fid');

    $subquery_2 = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('title','type'))
    ->fields('i', array('field_image_fid'))
    ->fields('f', array('uri'))
    ->condition('n.title', '%'. db_like($keys) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->condition('type', array('organization'))
    ->range(0,5);
    $subquery_2->leftJoin('field_data_field_image', 'i', 'i.entity_id = n.nid');
    $subquery_2->leftJoin('file_managed', 'f', 'f.fid = i.field_image_fid');

    $query = $subquery_1->union($subquery_2);
    $f->fb((string)$query);
    $result = $query
  ->execute();
```

Now the query return People and Organizations together and limited to 5. Here is the print of the query:

```
SELECT n.title AS title, n.type AS type, i.field_image_fid AS field_image_fid, f.uri AS uri FROM {node} n LEFT OUTER JOIN {field_data_field_image} i ON i.entity_id = n.nid LEFT OUTER JOIN {file_managed} f ON f.fid = i.field_image_fid WHERE (n.title LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE '\\') AND (type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1)) LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0 UNION SELECT n.title AS title, n.type AS type, i.field_image_fid AS field_image_fid, f.uri AS uri FROM {node} n LEFT OUTER JOIN {field_data_field_image} i ON i.entity_id = n.nid LEFT OUTER JOIN {file_managed} f ON f.fid = i.field_image_fid WHERE (n.title LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_2 ESCAPE '\\') AND (type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_3)) LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could include a version of the plain SQL that produces accurate results, it'll make it easier to debug

Answer (score 2):

Create both subqueries separately, with their limits. Then, use:

```
$query = $subquery_1->union($subquery_2);
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hello, I just tried your solution but it doesn't work. Only results from $subquery_1 are returned.. For the moment it's only working with db_query, which is a hassle.

Comment: @118218 Oh. Then I guess it's a job for support request or bugreport to core. Looks like something got skewed up in optimization of query builder. Could you show us a query rendered by it? `print (string)$query;` And make 1st query limit 3, 2nd query limit 5 so we could see what goes where, please. For debug's sake.

Comment: Where can I post a bugreport to core please?

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?categories=All

Answer (score 1):

looks like there is small bug in Drupal.
but there is workaround:

```
$subquery_1 = db_select('node', 'n')
->range(0,4);

$subquery_2 = db_select('node', 'n')
->range(0,8);

$query = $subquery_1->union($subquery_2);
```

->range(0,4); is for the first query 
and ->range(0, 8) is for both queries.

Problem is that $subquery_1->union doesn't add () around 2nd query.

issue with this approach is that if 1st query returns less than 4 rows then 2nd will return more to make 8